# Increase the values in <td> tags by a fixed percentage using PHP

Tags: php, html, string

I want to find and change multiple prices using php. e.g. increase/decrease 20% to all numbers.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>product name</td>
<td>$88</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>product name</td>
<td>$98</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>product name</td>
<td>$78</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>product name</td>
<td>$106</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>product name</td>
<td>$188</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Expected result:**

Increase 20%:

```
$88 x 20% + $88 => $105.6
$98 x 20% + $98 => $117.6
...
```

**What I've tried so far:**

I've tried to use a fucntion to get string (price number) between `$` and `</td>` then change it:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}
```

But it didn't work out very well. How can I correctly achieve this?

Comment: Please post the expected result (along with what you've tried so far).

Comment: Don't use string or regexp searching for HTML, use a DOM parser library.

Comment: What language used to do that ? you can do it in javascript or server language like php

Comment: @JohnTaa: It's been tagged with PHP, so I assume the OP wants to do it in PHP.

Comment: Then, if that case you can use html dom parser

Comment: @JohnTaa could you post a full code? Im a newbie learning php.

Comment: preg_replace_callback(); is the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an HTML parser to achieve this. Here is a solution using the built-in [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php%E2%80%8E) class:

```
$percentage = 20;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('td') as $tag) {
    if (preg_match('/\$(\d+)/', strval($tag->nodeValue), $matches)) {
        $currVal = $matches[1];
        $newVal = $currVal + ($currVal * $percentage / 100);
        $tag->nodeValue = '$'. $newVal;
    }
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

The regular expression `/\$(\d+)/` is used to check if the node contains a value of the format `$<any_number>`.

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/102112)

Comment: @jlee: Happy to have helped!

Answer (score 2):

If you must do it using string functions instead of HTML DOM Parser, you can use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback):

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('#(<td>\$)(\d+)(</td>)#', function($match) {
    return $match[1] . $match[2]*1.20 . $match[3];
}, $html);
```